# maven android plugin , app does not install on phone when google play service is used

Tags: android, android-maven-plugin

I am developing one of the application for android using android maven plugin . application works well till i dont provide google play service (GPS) as dependency ( it took me really too much time to install google play service in local repo which seem to be working fine now). Problem i am facing is the application does not install on device as soon as i provide GPS as dependency.

On one device i am getting certificate issue and on another one i am getting  parse unexpected error.

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Krish